# Sum two edittext and get result in third one

Tags: android

I want to sum the numbers entered in two `EditText` then when the button is clicked I want the sum to be showed in the third `EditText` but it seems something is wrong.

This is my code:

```
result = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    nb1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nb1);
    nb2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nb2);
    nb3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nb3);


    }

    public void result (View v){
        String n1 = nb1.getText().toString();
        int n11 = Integer.parseInt(n1);

        String n2 = nb2.getText().toString();
        int n22 = Integer.parseInt(n2);


        nb3.setText(n11 + n22);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
nb3.setText(n11 + n22);
```

to

```
 nb3.setText(String.valueOf(n11 + n22));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use following code.

```
nb3.setText(String.valueOf(n11 + n22));
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
nb3.setText(n11 + n22);
```

to

```
nb3.setText(String.valueOf(n11 + n22));
```

setText treats integers as a resource ID which is why you need to explicitly convert it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

> Do the following:

```
 int num1 = Integer.parseInt(edit1.getText().toString());
 int num2 = Integer.parseInt(edit2.getText().toString());

 edit3.setText(String.valueOf(num1+num2));//this you need to do
```

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
nb3.setText("" + n11 + n22);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will show `NumberFormatException` if you press the button without entering the value in the edittext. So do like this

```
public void result (View v){

try
{
        int sum = 0;
        String n1 = nb1.getText().toString();
        int n11 = Integer.parseInt(n1);

        String n2 = nb2.getText().toString();
        int n22 = Integer.parseInt(n2);
        sum = n11 + n22;

        nb3.setText("Sum is = " + sum);  // nb3.setText(" " + sum); if you don't want only result to be displayed.
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
}
```